# compare list and array

Tags: java

I need to compare the value from List with the value from array.
I wrote the following:

```
public class JavaApplication3 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic hereut
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("test");
    l.add("b");
    String v = "";
    String s = "";
    String[] arr = {"test", "c", "b"};

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++){
        v = "";
        s = "";
        //System.out.println(l.get(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
            if (l.get(i).equals(arr[j])){
                s = i + "";
            }else{
                s = arr[i];
            }
            v = v + s + ",";                   
        }  
        System.out.println(v);          
    }

}
```

}

I obtain the following
0,test,test,
c,c,1
but I need the result like this:
0, c, 1,

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your expected result I guess the requirement like that:

for each element in the array, check if it is on the list. If it is on the list, print the index from the list for this element, otherwise print the element itself. So the algorithm should do:

```
array[0] = "test" -> found at index 0 -> print "0"
array[1] = "c"    -> not found        -> print "c"
array[2] = "b"    -> found at index 1 -> print "1"
```

The outer loop should iterate over the array. Then, for each array item, iterate over the list until you find the same element. For a first draft, don't collect the output in a string but print it immediatly. You can create the string when the algorithm works as expected.

Comment: A lot of thanks Andreas and all you guys. Good idea :). Silly question as a beginner. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic hereut
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("test");
        l.add("b");
        String v = "";
        String s = "";
        String[] arr = {"test", "c", "b"};
        int pointer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++){
                        //System.out.println(l.get(i));
            for (; pointer < arr.length;){
                if (l.get(i).equals(arr[pointer])){
                    s = i + "";
                    v = v + s + ",";
                    pointer++;
                    break;
                }else{
                    s = arr[i];
                }
                pointer++;
                v = v + s + ",";
            }

        }
        System.out.println(v);

    }
```

Comment: expected

not a statement

';' expected

incompatible types
  required: boolean
  found:    int

Comment: @coco Corrected my answer. Check that

Comment: I run the code, it is woring, cause You put v = "" in foreach loop, it was wiping, not fixed

Answer (score 0):

You have six iterations, each of which inserts something into the output.

You want three iterations, each of which checks for membership in the first list. You can do that with the `List.contains()` method. (If the list were long, you might want to consider using a `Set` instead of a `List`, to allow checking set membership more quickly.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to break things down to their high level steps.

```
For each string in the array
    find its place in the list
    if the item is in the list
        print its position
    else
        print the missing string
    print a common and space
```

Once you have this you can spot that `find its place in the list` could be a method that returns the place in the list or -1 if it isn't in the list. Here's what I made (might have renamed a few things and used a StringBuilder but you can ignore that for the moment).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<String> listToSeach = new ArrayList<String>();
        listToSeach.add("test");
        listToSeach.add("b");

        final String[] arrayElementsToFind = { "test", "c", "b" };

        final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (final String string : arrayElementsToFind) {
            final int firstIndex = findFirstIndex(listToSeach, string);
            if (firstIndex > -1) {
                output.append(firstIndex);
            } else {
                output.append(string);
            }
            output.append(", ");
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    private static int findFirstIndex(final List<String> list,
            final String element) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(element)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I suggest this:

```
     List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
     l.add("test");
     l.add("b");
     String[] arr = {"test", "c", "b"};

     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i){

       if(l.contains(arr[i]))
         s = ""+l.indexOf(arr[i]);
       else
         s = arr[i];

       v = v + s + ",";
      }
```

If got what you saying correct,I think this is less verbose